# Diesel ORM error: no method `eq` on type `ID`

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to create a database to hold a table called 'MyTable', where I will upload a file to the database. I ran through the tutorial for diesel ORM linked here: http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html
I have an automatic generated schema for my table:

```
    diesel::table! {
        MyTable (ID) {
            ID -> Integer,
            ContentType -> Text,
            AttachmentName -> Text,
            AttachmentData -> Binary,
        }
    }
```

I ran into an issue where I it is throwing me an error like so:

```
no method `eq` on type `ID`rust-analyzerunresolved-method
no method `eq` on type `ContentType`rust-analyzerunresolved-method
no method `eq` on type `AttachmentName`rust-analyzerunresolved-method
no method `eq` on type `AttachmentData`rust-analyzerunresolved-method
```

This is my Cargo.toml:

```
    [package]
    name = "FileControl"
    version = "0.1.0"
    edition = "2021"
    default-run = "my-binary"

    [dependencies]
    Inflector = "0.11.4"
    ccase = "0.4.1"
    chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
    diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["sqlite","chrono"] }
    smartcore = {version = "0.3.0", features=["serde"]}
    dotenvy = "0.15"
    kv-derive = "1.0.1"
    proc-macro-error = "1.0.4"
    rocket = "0.4.11"
    serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
    serde_derive = "1.0.151"
    serde_json = "1.0"
    rocket_contrib = { version = "0.4.11", features = ["json"] }
    cargo-watch = "8.3.0"
    rustc-serialize = "0.3.24"
    base64 = "0.21.0"
    rocket-multipart-form-data = "0.10.5"
    uuid = { version = "1.3.0", features = ["v4"] }
    mime_guess = "2.0.4"
    dirs-2 = "3.0.1"


    [[bin]]
    name = "my-binary"
    path = "src/main.rs"
```

And this is an example of what I would be trying for:

```
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    pub fn establish_connection() -> SqliteConnection {
        dotenv().ok();
        let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
        SqliteConnection::establish(&database_url)
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
    }


    pub fn create_attachment(
        conn: &mut SqliteConnection,
        file: Vec<u8>,
        file_name: String,
        content_type: String,
    ) {
        let new_file = NewAttachment {
            AttachmentData: file,
            AttachmentName: file_name,
            ContentType: content_type,
        };
        diesel::insert_into(attachment_schema::table)
            .values(&new_file)
            .execute(conn)
            .expect("Error inserting data into database");
    }
    fn option_vec_to_slice(opt_vec: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> &'static [u8] {
        match opt_vec {
            Some(vec) => Box::leak(vec.into_boxed_slice()),
            None => &[],
        }
    }

    pub fn download_db_file(
        id: i32,
    ) -> io::Result<std::fs::File> {
        let connection = &mut establish_connection();
        let file_data = attachment_schema::table
            .filter(attachment_schema::ID.eq(id))
            .first::<attachment_model>(connection)
            .unwrap();
        let data = file_data.File;
        let file_name = file_data.FileName.unwrap();
        let download_dir = match dirs_2::download_dir() {
            Some(path) => path,
            None => {
                return Err(std::io::Error::new(
                    std::io::ErrorKind::NotFound,
                    "Download directory not found",
                ))
            }
        };
        let file_path = download_dir.join(&file_name);
        let mut file = std::fs::File::create(&file_path)?;
        let data_ref: &[u8] = option_vec_to_slice(data);
        file.write_all(data_ref)?;
        Ok(file)
    }
```

I have tried googling and using chatGPT to find the fix. I have deleted my Cargo.lock and re compiled, `cargo clean`, `cargo update`, and a numch of other methods. I have even deleted everthing and started all over again. And still have the same issue

Comment: What do your imports look like? Do you have `diesel::ExpressionMethods` or `diesel::prelude::*` imported?

Comment: Yes, I have                             use diesel::prelude::*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does only contain output from `rust-analyzer`. This tool is known to not being able to represent all valid rust code correctly. If your code compiles with `rustc` that's very likely another issue of that kind. You should fill an issue in [the rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer) repository in that case.

Comment: Switched to the pre-release version of rust-analyzer to bypass this issue